# Cant connect my node.js server to Angular frontend client

Tags: angular

I built a server with node.js and express and connected it to a postgres database. Using postman, I am able to see that my endpoints are working and properly posting/deleting/getting items from my database.

I created a frontend with Angular and created a service.ts file with a getTodos() method. I believe I added everything I need to that method and i am printing the results. I am subscribed to that method in my component file and I get 2 different responses in my console.

1. This huge chuck of objects that contains the data I want plus a bunch more nonsense.

```json
{
  "command": "SELECT",
  "rowCount": 4,
  "oid": null,
  "rows": [
    {
      "todo_id": 7,
      "description": "travel",
      "title": "I need to schedule covid tests",
      "date": null
    },
    {
      "todo_id": 8,
      "description": "travel",
      "title": "I need to schedule covid tests",
      "date": null
    },
    {
      "todo_id": 10,
      "description": "I need to schedule covid tests",
      "title": "travel",
      "date": "2022-04-23T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "todo_id": 11,
      "description": "I need to get this done",
      "title": "tech interview",
      "date": "2022-04-30T05:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "fields": ...
}
```

2. two errors that both say......Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

I will try to share what I am seeing. Thanks

here is the html that is trying to use the data

```html
<div 
  class="card"
  *ngFor="let todo of filteredTodos "
  [title]="todo.todoTitle"
  [style.width.rem]="cardHeightAndWidth"
  [style.height.rem]="cardHeightAndWidth"
  [style.margin.rem]="cardMargin"
>
```

Here is the service file

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ITodo } from './todo';
    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TodoService {
  private rootUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3000/todos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTodos(): Observable<ITodo[]> {
    return this.http.get<ITodo[]>(this.rootUrl).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log('All data', JSON.stringify(data));
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and here is the component file that it is subscribing

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe({
    next: todos => {

      this.todos = todos;

      this.filteredTodos = todos;
    },
    error: err => this.errorMessage = err
  });
}
```

Here is the backend of the project

```
    const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');


const pool = require("./db");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


//routes

//get all todos

app.get("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const todoList = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todo");

    res.json(todoList);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//create a todo

app.post("/todo", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, description, date } = req.body;
    const newTodo = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO todo (title, description, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *",
      [title, description, date]
    );

    res.json(newTodo.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

// update
app.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params; // where
    const { description, title } = req.body; // set

    const updateTodo = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE todo SET description = $1 WHERE todo_id = $2",
      [description, id]
    );

    res.json("updated todo");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//delete
app.delete("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const deleteTodo = await pool.query("DELETE FROM todo WHERE todo_id = $1", [
      id
    ]);
    res.json("todo was deleted");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
});

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(3000 || PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

I also tried changing the subscribe function to hit data.rows and got the error message `Property 'rows' does not exist of type 'ITodo[]`

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
   this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(
     (data: ITodo[]) => {
       this.todos = data.rows; // make sure that data is an array

       this.filteredTodos = this.todos;
     },
     (error: String) => (this.errorMessage)
   );

  }
```

This is the ITodo[]

```
export interface ITodo {
  todoId: number;
  todoTitle: string;
  todoDueDate: Date;
  todoDescription: string;
  todoTags: string[];
  

}
```

here is the console.log todos in the subscribe method

```
    {command: 'SELECT', rowCount: 4, oid: null, rows: Array(4), fields: Array(4), …}
RowCtor: null
command: "SELECT"
fields: Array(4)
0: {name: 'todo_id', tableID: 24580, columnID: 1, dataTypeID: 23, dataTypeSize: 4, …}
1: {name: 'description', tableID: 24580, columnID: 2, dataTypeID: 1043, dataTypeSize: -1, …}
2: {name: 'title', tableID: 24580, columnID: 3, dataTypeID: 1043, dataTypeSize: -1, …}
3: {name: 'date', tableID: 24580, columnID: 5, dataTypeID: 1082, dataTypeSize: 4, …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
oid: null
rowAsArray: false
rowCount: 4
rows: Array(4)
0: {todo_id: 7, description: 'travel', title: 'I need to schedule covid tests', date: null}
1: {todo_id: 8, description: 'travel', title: 'I need to schedule covid tests', date: null}
2: {todo_id: 10, description: 'I need to schedule covid tests', title: 'travel', date: '2022-04-23T05:00:00.000Z'}
3: {todo_id: 11, description: 'I need to get this done', title: 'tech interview', date: '2022-04-30T05:00:00.000Z'}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
_parsers: Array(4)
0: null
1: null
2: null
3: null
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
_types:
binary: {}
text: {}
_types: {arrayParser: {…}, builtins: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

This is All Data from the service file

```
All data `{"command":"SELECT","rowCount":4,"oid":null,"rows":[{"todo_id":7,"description":"travel","title":"I need to schedule covid tests","date":null},{"todo_id":8,"description":"travel","title":"I need to schedule covid tests","date":null},{"todo_id":10,"description":"I need to schedule covid tests","title":"travel","date":"2022-04-23T05:00:00.000Z"},{"todo_id":11,"description":"I need to get this done","title":"tech interview","date":"2022-04-30T05:00:00.000Z"}],"fields":[{"name":"todo_id","tableID":24580,"columnID":1,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"description","tableID":24580,"columnID":2,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":259,"format":"text"},{"name":"title","tableID":24580,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":54,"format":"text"},{"name":"date","tableID":24580,"columnID":5,"dataTypeID":1082,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null,null,null,null],"_types":{"_types":{"arrayParser":{},"builtins":{"BOOL":16,"BYTEA":17,"CHAR":18,"INT8":20,"INT2":21,"INT4":23,"REGPROC":24,"TEXT":25,"OID":26,"TID":27,"XID":28,"CID":29,"JSON":114,"XML":142,"PG_NODE_TREE":194,"SMGR":210,"PATH":602,"POLYGON":604,"CIDR":650,"FLOAT4":700,"FLOAT8":701,"ABSTIME":702,"RELTIME":703,"TINTERVAL":704,"CIRCLE":718,"MACADDR8":774,"MONEY":790,"MACADDR":829,"INET":869,"ACLITEM":1033,"BPCHAR":1042,"VARCHAR":1043,"DATE":1082,"TIME":1083,"TIMESTAMP":1114,"TIMESTAMPTZ":1184,"INTERVAL":1186,"TIMETZ":1266,"BIT":1560,"VARBIT":1562,"NUMERIC":1700,"REFCURSOR":1790,"REGPROCEDURE":2202,"REGOPER":2203,"REGOPERATOR":2204,"REGCLASS":2205,"REGTYPE":2206,"UUID":2950,"TXID_SNAPSHOT":2970,"PG_LSN":3220,"PG_NDISTINCT":3361,"PG_DEPENDENCIES":3402,"TSVECTOR":3614,"TSQUERY":3615,"GTSVECTOR":3642,"REGCONFIG":3734,"REGDICTIONARY":3769,"JSONB":3802,"REGNAMESPACE":4089,"REGROLE":4096}},"text":{},"binary":{}},"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":false}`
```

Comment: can you share your backend code

Comment: this.filteredTodos = todos?.rows

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz I just shared the backend code

Comment: @MikeOne I tried hitting this.filteredTodos = todos?.rows and i get the same error message of 'rows does not exist on ITodo[]'

Comment: can you share your **ITodo** interface and console.log todos in subscribe method

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz Just posted it

Comment: can you plz share the output of console.log in the service file (All Data)

Comment: @raju just shared

Comment: Just figured it out! the issue was in the server. I was sending unnecessary data in my get request up to the client. I went into the get function in the server and changed the res.data to res.data.rows. That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this code:

```
 this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(
    (data: todos) => {

      this.todos = data; // make sure that data is an array

      this.filteredTodos = todos;
    },
    (error: err) => this.errorMessage = err
  );
```

Comment: I tried the code and I am still getting the same messages in my console. Any other advice that i can try in conjunction? @raju